# React with TypeScript + Jest + Enzyme -- Error Test Expected 1 arguments, but got 2

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm a React developer, new to Typescript and I need some help in a rendering test that has several recurring errors and doesn't seem to have a solution :/

*index.spec.tsx*

```
import Enzyme, { mount } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17";
import { expect } from "@jest/globals";
import { findByTestId } from "../../../utils/testUtils";
import { Button, ButtonProps } from "../index";


Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

  const defaultProps: ButtonProps = {
    text: 'string',
    width: 'string',
    type: 1,
    disable: true,
  };

const setup = (props = {}) =>
  mount(<Button {...defaultProps} {...props} />);

describe("<Button />", () => {
  const wrapper = setup();
  test("renders increment button", () => {

    const appComponent = findByTestId(wrapper, "button");

    expect(appComponent.length).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

*index.tsx*

```
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */

import { Container } from './style';

export interface ButtonProps {
  // Props for Element
  width: string;
  text: string;
  type: Number;

  // Renders the date
  element?: React.ReactNode;
  disable: boolean;
}

export function Button({ disable, type, element, text, width }: ButtonProps) {
  
  return (
    <Container 
      data-testid="button"
      disable={disable}
      typeButton={type}
      width={width}
    >
      {element}
      {text}
    </Container>
  );

}
```

*setupTest.ts*

```
 /**
  * Searches inside passed wrapper nodes that has the passed dataTestid.
  * @param wrapper {ShallowWrapper}
      * @param dataTestid {String}
  * @returns List of nodes with defined testid.
  */

 interface TestProps {
    wrapper: any;
    dataTestid: string;
 }

  export const findByTestId = ({wrapper, dataTestid}: TestProps) => {
    return wrapper.find(`[data-testid="${dataTestid}"]`);
};
```

*setupTest.ts*

```
 /**
  * Searches inside passed wrapper nodes that has the passed dataTestid.
  * @param wrapper {ShallowWrapper}
      * @param dataTestid {String}
  * @returns List of nodes with defined testid.
  */

 interface TestProps {
    wrapper: any;
    dataTestid: string;
 }

  export const findByTestId = ({wrapper, dataTestid}: TestProps) => {
    return wrapper.find(`[data-testid="${dataTestid}"]`);
};
```

*setupTests.ts*

```
// jest-dom adds custom jest matchers for asserting on DOM nodes.
// allows you to do things like:
// expect(element).toHaveTextContent(/react/i)
// learn more: https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";

import { configure } from 'enzyme'
import Adapter from "@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17";


configure({
  adapter: new Adapter(),
  disableLifecycleMethods: true,
});
```

O erro é **Test suite failed to run

```
src/shared/components/Button/__tests__/index.espec.tsx:25:48 - error TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.

25     const appComponent = findByTestId(wrapper, "button");**
```

This is the same stack that I used to perform tests on Js and I never had problems, someone already performed tests by Typescript and would be able to help? I've already tried using toBeInTheDocument but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `findByTestId` function expects an object: `findByTestId = ({wrapper, dataTestid}: TestProps) => ...`

You need to pass an object like this instead:

```js
const appComponent = findByTestId({ wrapper, dataTestId: "button" });
```

Alternatively, you can rewrite the function to expect 2 arguments like this:

```js
export const findByTestId = (wrapper: any, dataTestid: string) =>
  wrapper.find(`[data-testid="${dataTestid}"]`);
```